# edit more posts on one page

Tags: php, cakephp

I want to edit more posts on one edit page. By cookbook there are in every post row 3 actions, edit, view and delete.

But now I need to create 1 edit page with a group of posts and there I want to edit them.

In controller I fetched rows I need (2 rows of posts).

```
$posts= $this->Post->find('list', array('conditions' => array('task_id' => $taskId)));
```

then throw foreach I filled data:

```
$this->request->data[$i]
```

and in view when debuging

```
foreach ($this->request->data as $key => $value) {debug($value);}
```

with these I get 2 post data arrays: array(1) and array(2)

But I don't know how to edit them in forms. I tried to put (vulgaris) edit rows in foreach but I get 2 same forms(with data from array(1))

```
foreach ($this->request->data as $key => $value) {

    echo $this->Form->create('Post');
    echo $this->Form->input('id');
    echo $this->Form->input('task_id');
    echo $this->Form->input('note');
    echo $this->Form->input('priority');
    echo $this->Form->input('results_link');
    echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit'));
}
```

I don't know where to put $value from foreach.

These is only an example of form. posts because posts are in cookbook.

And maybe someone knows if I will have a problem when I will need to save edited arrays of data. (use 1 submit on the end of the form or in every row 1)

Comment: Create the form inside the loop and set the values.

Comment: i tryed in foreach, like in example..

Comment: SO what is the problem in that?

Comment: becouse with foreach i get vars $value and $key, but i don use them nowhere, becouse i dont know where to pot them.

Comment: i resolved it:like these: foreach($this->request->data as $key => $this->request->data){}

Comment: but now i have problem. i need to put submit button in every row. and than it works normal. if i put only 1 submit on the end, after all posts, and than debug data that is sended to controller, there is only last post data array. please can someone give me advice.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolved with: (need to turn my brain ON)

```
foreach($this->request->data as $key => $this->request->data){}
```